# add new item in the specific position but can't remove old item in that positon

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i want to add item at particular postion and add other item at that position. I have this JSON

```
key: user_login_users
surname: "smith"
name: "patrick"
```

Now i want delate patrick smith and set new item.My HTML code:

```
//for delate particular position
var get_delate_position= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users"));
var new_delate_position = storedNames.slice(pos+1,get_delate_position.length);
localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify(arr1));

var arr1=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users"));
arr1[pos].name=nome_users.value;
arr1[pos].surname=cognome_users.value;  
localStorage.setItem("nome_users", arr1[pos].name);
localStorage.setItem("surname_users", arr1[pos].surname);
var t={
    name:arr1[pos].name,
    surname:arr1[pos].surname
    }
arr1.push(t);
localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

The local storage add one new postion in this memory, set new item but don't remove old item patrick smith.Why?How can i do?

Comment: Please provide full code. For example, you are using variable `arr1` which for us  is undeclared.

Comment: Sorry i was wrong to write key:user_login_users
surname: "smith"
name: "patrick".Arr1 contains surname: "smith"
name: "patrick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to your question yesterday, the same rules apply.

1. Get the latest value from local storage, by calling `localstorage.getItem`
2. apply your changes; be it a new item, removing an existing one or changing an existing one. doesn't really matter.
3. Persist the changes again, by calling `localstorage.setItem`

see the example below, you can [try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/z02dp7st/)
It has an example for an Add, Delete and change of existing entry.

```
// Setup localstorage for this example: 
localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify([{
  name: "Elena",
  surname: "Rondina"
}, {
  name: "Lars",
  surname: "Codemonkey"
}]));

// adding a new user
// Retrieve the user_login_users from local storage
var usersInLocalStorageAdd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users") || []);
console.log("before doing add:", usersInLocalStorageAdd)
// add the user to the object
usersInLocalStorageAdd.push({
  name: "Jacky",
  surname: "Chan"
});
// persist the change to local storage
localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify(usersInLocalStorageAdd));
// the new user is new persisted
// the user at pos is now deleted:
var afterAdd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users") || []);
console.log("after add:", afterAdd)


// Deleting an entry:
// Retrieve the user_login_users from local storage
var usersInLocalStorageDelete = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users") || []);
console.log("before doing delete:", usersInLocalStorageDelete)

// remove a single user from local storage, at the specified postion:
var pos = 0;
if (usersInLocalStorageDelete.length > pos + 1) {
  usersInLocalStorageDelete.splice(pos, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify(usersInLocalStorageDelete));

  // the user at pos is now deleted:
  var afterDelete = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users") || []);
  console.log("after delete:", afterDelete)
}


// Modify existing user:
// Retrive the value from local storage again. 
var usersInLocalStorageForModification = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users") || []);
console.log('before change', usersInLocalStorageForModification)
// we setup some values we want to apply
var nome_users = {
  value: "John"
};
var cognome_users = {
  value: "Smith"
};
// // pos is still zero. we will edit the first first entry.
usersInLocalStorageForModification[pos].name = nome_users.value;
usersInLocalStorageForModification[pos].surname = cognome_users.value;
// at this point the entry is modified. we need to store it again in order to persist this.
localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify(usersInLocalStorageForModification));

// the user at pos is now changed:
var afterModify = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users") || []);
console.log("after change:", afterModify)
```